# SendMessage from Android mobile service to Wear not received

Tags: android, wear-os

I've been battling this for a while. every test says success, but no message is received. I'm sending from a WearableListenerService to Wear as a reply to a message i've just received.

sending (from mobile WearListenerService):

```
 @Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent)
{

        apiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(Wearable.API).build();
        ConnectionResult connectionResult = apiClient.blockingConnect(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        if (!connectionResult.isSuccess())
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to connect to GoogleApiClient.");
            return;
        }

        nodeID = messageEvent.getSourceNodeId();
        sendReplyAsync("some reply");

}

private void sendReplyAsync(String msg)
{

    PendingResult<MessageApi.SendMessageResult> messageResult = Wearable.MessageApi
            .sendMessage(apiClient, nodeID, REPLY_PATH,
                         msg.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

    messageResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<MessageApi.SendMessageResult>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResult(MessageApi.SendMessageResult result)
        {
            confirm(result.getStatus().isSuccess());
        }
    });
}
```

The log shows that the reply is sent. And If i query the connected nodes, the one that im sending to is indeed correct.

then over in Wear:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    apiClient =
            new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(Wearable.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .build();

    apiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    Wearable.MessageApi.removeListener(apiClient, apiClientMessageListener);
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle)
{
    if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "adding message listener");
    Wearable.MessageApi.addListener(apiClient, apiClientMessageListener);

    // sends message here to mobile.
}


 private MessageApi.MessageListener apiClientMessageListener = new             MessageApi.MessageListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent)
    {
        String path = messageEvent.getPath();
        if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "received message from " + path);

        // nothing ever received here
    }
};
```

As far as i can tell, everything is OK. Could there be something weird about sending from a service. When i sent from the MainActivity it worked, but now i have to put the sending in a service.

any ideas appreciated. thanks.

Comment: To start, I suggest you do the following: when you call apiClient.connect(), you need to make sure that the connection has been established before adding your listener. You must have onConnected() defined somewhere on the wear, so log a line there and move the line that adds the message listener to onConnected(). Is it correct that your mobile side receives messages from the wear side?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I changed the Wear code as suggested but there is still no receipt. Yes, sending from Wear to mobile works fine, just the reply is lost.